# How to mock a method that has 2 return values: an integer and an OrderedDict, in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

How to mock a method that has 2 return values: an integer and an OrderedDict, in Python?

Tried searching on the internet but didn't find anything.

Comment: There are never two return values. But there may be a tuple with two items.

Comment: There's no such thing as 2 (or more) return values. if you ever see ``return value1, value2`` then it's a tuple (w/o parens) and it's the same as writing ``return (value1, value2,)`` which makes it more obvious that it's a tuple

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) object:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock


def myfunc():
    print("My func")
    return 1


myfunc = Mock(return_value=(11, OrderedDict({1: 1})))


class Tester(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_myfunc(self):
        res = myfunc()
        self.assertTrue(res[0] == 11)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(res[1], OrderedDict))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```